# ListView: How to show an Empty View programmaticaly?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have been searching for it here , in some answers . But the answers weren't enough , cause i  use a Layout to include elements of ListView (but no a ListView itself) .

How can i show an empty view , which is not in the XML layout file , and all it programmaticaly?

Comment: Just out of my curiosity: why would you want to do it in code when the "android:empty" id trick would do (as far as I'm seeing, of course, hence the question) the same result?

Comment: @David Cause in my case , i'm not using a ListView , but a ListActivity + XXXXLayout . When i use the android:empty in this case , i'm including it in the item , but that cause of course doesn't run . If you can't or you make this way your listActivity , you have no more option that this one.

Comment: Ah, I thought you could just use a custom layout with your listactivity, then providing your own emptyview. I looked at your answer and saw the same behavior. But if you can't you can't... Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6):

I was searching for it , and i write this question in order to help another ones , this is the answer :

```
 TextView emptyView = new TextView(context);
 emptyView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
 emptyView.setText("This appears when the list is empty");
 emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 ((ViewGroup)list.getParent()).addView(emptyView);
 list.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Don't forget to use:

```
 emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 ((ViewGroup)list.getParent()).addView(emptyView);
```

Which is the part where all answers fail.